# Brazil DST no longer in use 2020 - intl.DateTimeFormat returns incorrect UCT date in Chrome

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-intl

Different Browsers are returning different dates for the same `intl.DateTimeFormat` function.

Brazil are not following Daylight saving this year 
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil?year=2020#targetText=Daylight%20Saving%20Time%20(DST)%20Not,was%20on%20February%2016%2C%202019

And `Intl.DateTimeFormat` appears to return the incorrect time (the example date below is in November 2019)

Example on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/waxekocaqa/edit?html,js,output

```js
const timestamp = new Date('2019-11-07T20:00:00Z');

const londonDf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  timeZone: 'Europe/London'
});

const saoPauloDf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'
});

console.log(londonDf.format(timestamp)); // 8:00 pm
console.log(saoPauloDf.format(timestamp)); // 6:00 pm (should be 5:00 pm)
```

The expected result for `saoPauloDf` should be `5:00 pm`, but please let me know if i missing something obvious.

Also, Safari shows the correct times, but Chrome does not

Comment: In which implementation? Safari shows 5 pm, Chrome 6 pm, Firefox 5 pm, Opera 6 pm. You'll have to test every implementation to determine which are correct and which aren't.

Comment: 5pm is the correct time when using a date/time in November

Comment: Run Windows Update?

Comment: @SalmanA—how will running Windows update fix various browser implementations that are largely independent of the particular OS version?

Comment: @Robg https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4507704/dst-changes-in-windows-for-brazil-and-morocco. If the browser relies on OS to get timezone info then OS itself must be up-to-date.

Comment: @SalmanA—implementations rely on the OS for host timezone settings, not the entire history of global timezone offsets plus representative locations such as might be held by the IANA Timezone Database. If the OS had such information, and implementations had access to it, why would two browsers on the same system report differences as indicated in my first comment?

Comment: @RobG Windows stores information about countries' timezone rules in registry. This database is updated with windows update ([see](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free/)). Now I get correct results on all browsers but incorrect on PHP, purely because PHP comes with its own tz database that does not automatically update itself.

Comment: @stuart are both browsers up-to-date?

Comment: @salmana - Yes, and I'm on a mac

Comment: @SalmanA–not everyone is running Windows, and not everyone running Windows can update to the latest (or even perhaps fairly recent) version. And I don't think you can assume even that all Windows browsers will use historic offset information in the registry. It's not a requirement of ECMA-262, so can't be assumed even for the most current browsers.